# Azure Alert Rules(Custom Log Search) how to get custom dimensions value into webhook

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have configured Application insights from API Management, Inside App Insights i have configured Alert rules, whenever there is a error, Alert will be triggered & a webhook will be invoked with the alert details.
[image]

---

In Query i have added customdimensions["Request-Body"] and customdimensions["Response-Body"], which is not getting listed in split-dimension dropdown,

the fileds which are listed in dropdown only comes in webhook, but i need customdimensions["Request-Body"] and customdimensions["Response-Body"] as well, how to get it.
[image]

Comment: This article seems to cover the issue:
https://camerondwyer.com/2020/05/26/how-to-use-application-insights-custom-properties-in-azure-monitor-log-kusto-queries/